# When to use Entity Manager in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

At the moment I am learning how to use Symfony2. I got to the point where they explain how to use Doctrine.

In the examples given they sometimes use the entity manager:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$products = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
        ->findAllOrderedByName();
```

and in other examples the entity manager is not used:

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);
```

So I actually tried the first example without getting the entity manager:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product');
$products = $repository->findAllOrderedByName();
```

and got the same results.

So when do i actually need the entity manager and when is it OK to just go for the repository at once?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looking at [`Controller`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html) `getDoctrine()` equals to `$this->get('doctrine')`, an instance of [`Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Registry.html). Registry provides:

- `getEntityManager()` returning [`Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html), which in turn provides `getRepository()`
- `getRepository()` returning [`Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html)

Thus, `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository()` equals `$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository()`.

Entity manager is useful when you want to persist or remove an entity:

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$em->persist($myEntity);
$em->flush();
```

If you are just fetching data, you can get only the repository:

```php
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product');
$product    = $repository->find(1);
```

Or better, if you are using custom repositories, wrap `getRepository()` in a controller function as you can get auto-completition feature from your IDE:

```php
/**
 * @return \Acme\HelloBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
 */
protected function getProductRepository()
{
    return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:Product');
}
```

Comment: I already knew I needed to use the entity manager when using `flush()`. Also the idea to use a `getProductRepository()` function is something that might be usefull, thanks!

Comment: @MatsRietdijk glad to be of help! I always wrap `$this->get('some service')` in custom functions in my `BaseController` to get auto completition...

Comment: What is the Location of `AcmeStoreBundle:Product ` where can i find `Product` in my Symfony Application.

Comment: `YouApplication\src\Bundle\ToolsBundle\Repository\ProductRepository.php`

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `getDoctrine()->getRepository()` is simply a shortcut to `getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository()`. Did not check the source code, but sounds rather reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do multiple operations with the entity manager (like get a repository, persist an entity, flush, etc), then get the entity manager first and store it in a variable. Otherwise, you can get the repository from the entity manager and call whatever method you want on the repository class all in one line. Both ways will work. It's just a matter of coding style and your needs.