# Symfony2 doctrine ManyToMany relation

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, dql

I'm a beginner on Synfony2 and doctrine usage. I've created two entities as following :

For EndUser Entity (extension of FOSUserBundle ):

```
/**
 * EndUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Core\CustomerBundle\Entity\EndUserRepository")
 */
class EndUser extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\GeneralBundle\Entity\Discipline", mappedBy="endusers")
     */
    private $discipline;
```

and for discipline entity

```
class Discipline {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\CustomerBundle\Entity\EndUser", inversedBy="discipline")
     */
    private $endusers;
```

When I did `"php app/console doctrine:schema:update -- force`,

`EndUser`, `Discipline` and `discipline_enduser` tables have been created.

When I run a standard SQL request through phpmyadmin as :

```
select t0.*
from
discipline t0,
discipline_enduser t2
where 
t2.enduser_id = 1
and 
t2.discipline_id = t0.id
```

I obtain the expected result as the list of discipline for a specific user.

My concern is how to implement the same using the Entity with Symfony2 & Doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend to use more natural language names for you relationships, like `disciplines` and `endUsers` since it is a `manyToMany` bond. Also, you need to create the `get` and `set` method for each. After you have prepared all your properties for an entity you should run the command to [Generate your getters and setters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters)

```
//this will generate all entities
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities BundleNamespace
```

After that, you can do things like :

```
$endUser->getDisciplines(); //return all disciplines of this user
$endUser->addDiscipline($someDiscipline); //add another discipline
$endUser->removeDiscipline($iAmABadDiscipline); //remove this discipline from this user
array $disciplines = [ ... ];
$endUser->setDisciplines($disciplines); // set multiple disciplines
```

Same logic applies to `Discipline` entity, ofcourse you should update them with an `EntityManager` for which you can read more in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847288/1423650).

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is amend your EndUser entity to include the following:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class EndUser extends BaseUser 
{
    private $discipline;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->discipline = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setDiscipline($discipline)
    {
        $this->discipline = $discipline;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDiscipline()
    {
        return $this->discipline;
    }
}
```

Then similarly amend Discipline, substituting endUser for discipline.

There is no need to create the intermediate entity.  Doctrine has already figured it out.  Neat, huh?!

Answer (score 0):

To make things more coherent, rename your class member to $disciplines (it's many-to-many, so there may be multiple disciplines in it). Then you need setters and getters in your entity to access the disciplines.

One way is to do this on the command line:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle:EndUser
```

This will add the required methods to your class. The unmodified version of the class file is backed up in EndUser.php~ in case anything is overwritten.

After doing this, you can just call the getter to obtain the disciplines:

```
$disciplines = $anEndUser->getDisciplines();
```

For example in a controller method:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $anEndUser = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('YourBundle:EndUser')
        ->find(1)
    ;
    $disciplines = $anEndUser->getDisciplines();
}
```